# Problem in selecting the distinct value in drupal 9

Tags: view, drupal, drupal-modules

I am having a problem displaying the distinct value in the table in Drupal 9.

I would like to view only a single AMC certificate for each Instrument displayed (referenced) in the current table/content.

But unfortunately, I am not able to do this by setting the distinct option in my view.

I am hereby attaching three images showing the problem, view, and query executed for view.

Help me to resolve this issue.

[image]

[image]

[image: Query Executed]

Comment: In the `Other` of the view builder > Query settings, you can check the DISTINCT checkbox.

Comment: It is not working if i select the view builder > Query settings. However, it should work. But in my case it is not working

Comment: Unfortunately that is all i can do, another way is to create a custom page or block which will allow you to handle the build of query process completely.